# Как добавить значение переменных в объект players чтобы решить следующую задачу?

Tags: python

Каждому члену футбольной команды решили заказать новую пару кроссовок. Необходимо написать программу, в которую можно будет внести имена и размеры футболистов и вывести по имени человека его размер. Если такого человека нет, то вывести "Такого человека в команде нет".

```
name = input('Имя')
size = input('Размер')

n= int(input('Количество человек в команде'))
players = {}
players[name] = size

for i in range (n):
    name = input('Введите имя человека')

    if name in players:
        print(players[name])

    else:
        print('Такого человека в команде нет')
```

Comment: и в чем проблема? код не работает ?

Comment: Ввод тоже в цикле сделайте.